# Inserting into one table from multiple tables except uniques

Tags: sql, sqlite

Lets say I have 3 tables named A,B and C

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST A (ID integer primary key);`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST B (ID integer primary key);`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST C (IDA integer,IDB integer);`

If I want to make sure that there is one C (and only one C) for every A,B pair. How do I do it?

I tried:

`INSERT INTO C(IDA,IDB) SELECT A.ID, B.ID FROM A,B;`

And it does create a C from each A,B pair. But if its run again it will be created again. How do I modify the query it so that it only creates a new C when there is not already a C with A and B.

Lets Say I have a:
`A:1,2`
`B:1,2`
`C:(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)`
and then  B=3 is added. I want a query that will add `C:(1,3),(2,3)` and not any pair already in C.

Comment: Though it is difficult to format the question in an understandable manner, I would recommend you do so.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query. Hopefully it works for you.

```
INSERT INTO c (ida, idb)
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.id
FROM a, b

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM c
                  WHERE c.ida = a.id 
                    AND c.idb = b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO C(IDA,IDB) 
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, B.ID
FROM A,B
MINUS
SELECT IDA, IDB
FROM C;
```

One another possible way, efficient if A & B are small as cartesian join is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table C:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS C (IDA integer,IDB integer, UNIQUE (IDA, IDB) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);

SQLite will do all the work.